# modem/router > switch > multiple routers?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I have my house wired with cat 5 running to 7 rooms from the electrical panel

the ISP will come and install their modem which has a built in wireless router and wired ports (4 ports) by the electrical panel.

I want to connect the ISP's modem/router to the switch, which will be connected to the 7 rooms

I want to put wireless AC access points in rooms 1, 3, and 5, However, I also want the outlet in rooms 1, 3 and 5 to have a router/switch that will enable me to hard wire my various devices within those rooms....

Can I put regular wireless ac routers with wired ports at the end of the drops connected to the switch?

and of course, I want all 3 wireless routers at the end of the drops to broadcast the same wifi SSID so my wireless devices connect to the closest router....

is this possible?

Comment: Did you research this at all... this is a *classic* home install with multiple SOHO wireless routers, there are multiple tutorials online about how to set this up... one is a router/DHCP server, set the local IP addresses to unique values on all routers (192.16.1.1, .2, .3, .4, etc), the rest are dumbed down to switches with Wireless APs and the WAN ports are abandoned, set the same SSID and other settings for the Wireless but spread the channels.  Research, set it up, and if you have issues post your SPECIFIC questions here, we are not a tutorial service for readily available information.

Comment: If you want them to have the same SSID, then you pretty much _must_ switch all but one to "bridge" mode, otherwise the client devices will be very confused.

Comment: And the origin of this confusion would be...?

Comment: @grawity This doesn't make sense, why would clients get confused? Set AP1 to channel 1, AP2 to 6, AP3 to 11, AP4 to 1, etc, all with same SSID, the client will decide which one is best to connect to and when it's best to roam to another AP, this is by design and how it's intended to work.

Comment: @acejavelin: That's true, but that's also the _reason_ for confusion. When clients roam between APs, they expect to remain connected to the same LAN – they assume it's safe to roam because the IP address will remain the same, and TCP connections won't be interrupted. (I.e. APs are like switch ports, only wireless.) If you have several completely separate routers offering the same SSID, suddenly roaming clients end up in a different subnet, behind a different NAT, and so on. I've had that happen.

Comment: @grawity that's why you don't use them all as routers, only 1, if done correctly there is only one subnet, one WAN connection, one DHCP server... If there is confusion it's in the setup, not the client devices

Comment: @acejavelin: Hence the "bridge mode" comment.

Comment: @grawity The OP stated he had wired connectivity to all locations, wireless bridging is not required and would be detrimental

Comment: @acejavelin: That's ... not at all what I meant by "bridge mode".

Comment: @grawity but that **IS** what bridge mode means in SOHO wireless routers, thus the confusion... Simple networking between switches is not bridging. If you are using a nonstandard reference you should explain the definition in detail

Comment: @acejavelin: Huh? In most SOHO wireless routers I've used, "bridging" was always the alternative to "routing" – i.e. the OS would put the wifi interface in the same OS-level bridge (e.g. br0) as the Ethernet ports. The wireless kind you speak of, if present, seems to have always been labelled either "WDS bridging" or just "WDS".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and it is in fact a perfect system you're making. Just make sure that the wireless boxes you choose support both 802.11ac (5Ghz) and 802.11n (2.4Ghz). They should also support bridge mode so that the devices won't be behind two NATs. If you're in Europe, choose among channel 1, 5, 9 and 13, one for each AP. If you're in US choose 1, 6 and 11. 5 Ghz got no overlapping channels. If there is a lot of 2.4 Ghz AP in your neighborhood, it is a better idea to find one channel that is less in use and use this for all your APs. Bandwidth utilization is not as important as getting rid of collision which can be a major problem because of "hidden node". The reason you want wireless to support bridge mode is because it is easier to route packets to the correct place when they are initiated from outside. Then you only have to set port forwarding, dmz in one box, the modem.

You should also think about if you would want a box with QOS so that no user can harvest most of the bandwidth. Many programs can be aggressive at this, such as torrent clients. A QOS box can be set to fair share so that no private IP can get more than somebody else, using floor and roof rules. Also a good idea to choose one of the APs to be a RADIUS server and run 802.1x security. This way you can have account for each user and some guest accounts too. If you plan to run a file server you can also use this as RADIUS server. You would then run WPA2 in enterprise mode. The only difference the users will see is a demand from their client to type both username and password. If you want guests to be isolated from the home network, you could run one of the AP in NAT mode on its own subnet allowing it only to route through default gateway. If there are places in the future you would want high speed net but not wireless I suggest you use homeplug which use the el cable to traverse data. It is a very stable system which can give you up to a bandwidth of 1.2 Gbps. Standard is 500 Mbps.

Comment: Where in the link would the qos box go?  Also the reason I want multiple access points is because the the signal on the other side of the house is not as great .  Would turning one of those aps to radius only allow that specific ap to have radius Auth?